# Why doesn't CSS "height" behave like "width" on window resize?

Tags: html, css

If I set 100% width on an element in css this element will adjust when I resize my browser window.
If I instead set the height as 100% the element will not update when resizing my window, instead the content will cut-off if window is expanded beyond the initial 100% height.

Why is this?

EDIT: Scrolling is the issue. It will not resize on scroll. Leaving the site looking cut-off.

Comment: what browser do you use? I tested in chrome and all works fine. Provide your actual markup. For now I suspect that you have fixed height set on some of the parents.

Comment: it would be much better to post this to answer itself and with `CSS` also

Comment: Can you post some minimal sample code with this not working?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the div's height is being restricted by the fixed height of the body and html parent.

Try:

**The HTML**

```
<div id="full">
    Content
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#full {position: relative; display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #CCC;}
```

Or if you prefer: **the Full Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {height: 100%;}
            #full {position: relative; display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #CCC;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="full">
            Content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key is to set `height:100%` and the display property to `display:table;`

Answer (score 1):

`Height: 100%` means "be as tall as my parent element".  So, if your parent element only has a height of 300px, your child element can only be a maximum of 300px tall as well.  This is also true for width, but block level elements take up all of the horizontal space available to them by default.

Note that this does not apply to inline elements, they ignore height/width all together.

*Edit* Look at your elements:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

How tall is your `body` element?  Is it 100%?  How tall is your `html` element?  Is it 100%?

Comment: Yes, all the elements has a `height:100%`. But height seems to take height of window instead of height of the document. Resulting in a cut-off once you go passed 100%. (scroll)

Comment: @JimmyRare: This answer is complete: read the part about width and height of parent element carefully. Width and height of 100% never means the width and height of the document. FYI, there is no CSS workaround for this. This is how HTML behaves. You can use javascript and set height to calculated px value instead of % to solve this.

Comment: I probably was vague with my question. 
I should've asked why the dom is not re-rendered on scroll height-wise.

Answer (score 0):

It work fine try this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/obereb/3) 
there may be issue with your code

Comment: There is no content to scroll in your example.